# UI-Router dynamically set parent state at runtime

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to dynamically set the parent state of a ui-router state at runtime?

I have a case where I need to set a different parent state, depending on whether or not the user is logged in. I have a service that I can use to fetch this authentication status.

Comment: can you be more specific ? do you mean something like this? `parent.child` and `parent2.child` ?? how to move between them?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I want to be able to set parent or parent2. And I don't want to use separate routes -- I need to be able to set the parent dynamically.

Comment: i think that's not possible, in that case you can set the templates dynamically, or separate routes. i'd prefer dynamic templates to load different navbars according to the user

Comment: I kinda figured it wouldn't be possible -- good to know though. I'll give the dynamic templates a shot.