# dynamic ui-sref in html does not run, runs href tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am consuming a web service before navigating to a controller. and here I GET a web request and the result of this request I keep it in the variable    `$rootScope.userSesion` .This web service I want to run it every time I navigate to another view so I do not have to put the same code on each controller. :

```
angularRoutingApp.run(function($rootScope, $http){
    // this code is executed every time I change the view
    $transitions.onStart({ }, trans => {
    . 
    .
    .
    $rootScope.userSesion="gestionarUsuarios";
    })
    .
    .
    .
})
```

in the html view I'm putting my `$rootScope.userSesion` variable. when inspecting the element to which I want to click and that sends me to the state that I put in the **ui-sref**, does nothing and redirects me to another state('gestionarUsuarios'). the href tag attribute corresponds to the url of my current view.

[image]

when I click I should go to the "manageUsers" state but nothing happens. This is the code of my view.

```
<a class="columna_menu border_contenedor_seis" ui-sref="{{userSesion.estado}}">
 <div class="welle welle_seis"></div>
```

I want it when I click on the element to which I change the *ui-sref** allow me to navigate normally.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug this issue from 3 lines of code, but as variable `userSesion` is a type string, your ui-sref should look like `ui-sref="{{ userSesion }}.estado"`

Comment: Ok. Maybe I dont know what is the purpose of this approach. I only pointed out that you are mixing string with object. I think that this is against philosophy of angularJS routing and dynamic templating. You should make different routes for each session or dynamic template. [Same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759172/ui-router-dynamically-set-parent-state-at-runtime)